# Include form select value in URL

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I have a javascript function that currently changes the Submit action based on value of a variable called currentVal.  I do have a select within this form with an ID of TRADE_IN that I also want to pass to the next page.  How do I alter/add to this javascript to also submit this form select into the url so I can perform a `$trade = $_REQUEST['TRADE_IN'];` on the next page as well?

```
function changeSubmit(currentVal, id) {
    if(currentVal < 5) {
        $('#avgSubmit'+id).val('myVolvo.php?plan=gold&age=1-4 years');
    } else if(currentVal >=5 && currentVal < 10) {
        $('#avgSubmit'+id).val('myVolvo.php?plan=gold&age=5-9 years');
    } else {
        $('#avgSubmit'+id).val('myVolvo.php?plan=gold&age=10 years');
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `.val` to change the action attribute of the form ?

Comment: Can you show us your html ? The current way doesn't seem very efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jason's answer could work. You could store it in your $_SESSION var too!

Comment: I have a ton of calculations that come into play...I have to keep the javascript as is...how do I store that value in _SESSION?

Comment: I tried this with no luck?  what am I doing wrong?
<?php
session_start();
$_session['TRADE_IN'] = $_POST['TRADE_IN'];
?>

Comment: SESSIONS is the way to go, I'll post a new question with my troubles on creating and displaying the session, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me you could simply have this:

```
<form action="myVolvo.php" method="get">
    <input type="hidden" name="plan" value="gold" />
    <select name="age">
        <option value="1-4 years">1-4 years</option>
        <option value="5-9 years">5-9 years</option>
        <option value="10 years">10 years</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Where the hidden "plan" could also be a visible form element if needed.

Does this make sense, or am I missing something?